# Setting IBOutlet property in Xcode 4.2 issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, iboutlet

I am using a navigation based iPhone application, and I defined an IBOutlet propert in the inner view and synthesized it,

The issue is when I want to set the IBOutlet value before pushing the new view controller, the value won't be set.  Here is a snippet from the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    MealDetailViewController *mealViewController = [[MealDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MealDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    MealsModel *model = (MealsModel *)[_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(model.Name);// here it writes the name right as a string

    //mealViewController.lblName.text=model.Name;

    [[mealViewController lblName]setText:model.Name];
    [[mealViewController txtDesc]setText:model.Description];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mealViewController animated:YES];

    [mealViewController release];
}
```

I didn't face like these issues in the previous versions of Xcode.

Comment: Not sure why it would be, but `lblName` could be nil. I usually don't access outlets in this way. I would pass the `MealsModel` object to the `MealDetailViewController` and then let `MealDetailViewController` set it's own outlets in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @Mark Adams - it's probably because the view hasn't been loaded yet. And your comment sums up my answer in about 10% of the lines it took me to do it - I'd do exactly the same as you :)

Comment: The odd thing is that `-initWithNibName:bundle:` should be unarchiving the XIB, establishing the outlets and sending `-viewDidLoad`. I've noticed a few questions along these lines lately. Perhaps something has changed in iOS 5.

Comment: I've sometimes seen it decide not to instantiate the views until they're explicitly asked for (which, because I pass data around instead of reaching into other view controllers) has never been an issue for me (and i guess not for you either given your first comment). Because I tend to put everything ui related into viewDidLoad (or viewWillAppear:) I'm not sure when everything gets created; I just wait until I'm told that it has been!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's to do with when your view controller's views are being created.

When you do

```
[[mealViewController lblName] setText:model.Name];
```

you haven't loaded it's view yet so lblName will be `nil`.

Try either

(a) Explicitly asking for the view, triggering the subviews to be created :

```
[mealViewcontroller view];
[[mealViewController lblName]setText:model.Name];
[[mealViewController txtDesc]setText:model.Description];
```

or

(b) Letting the navigation controller create the views for you

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mealViewController animated:YES];

[[mealViewController lblName]setText:model.Name];
[[mealViewController txtDesc]setText:model.Description];
```

or

(c) Store the values in the mealViewController as properties

MealViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *lblNameString;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *txtDescString;
```

MealViewcontroller.m

```
@synthesize txtDescString, lblNameString;
```

and instead of setting the label directly, set the properties instead.

```
[mealViewController setLblNameString:model.Name];
[mealViewController setTxtDescString:model.Description];
```

Then, in your newWillAppear, setting them

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    lblName.text = lblNameString;
    txtDesc.text = txtDescString;
}
```

(c) is the more correct way to do it - (a) and (b) both fail if your view controller's view is unloaded by a low memory warning.

Comment: @Nidal Saed - just out of interest, did you do (a), (b) or (c) ?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is pass the *Meal object to the MealDetailViewController. Then use that to set the labels and such in the MealDetailViewController. Once I had a similar problem and found that I was initializing the property, a UILabel in ViewDidLoad of my receiving class so it was overwriting any passed in text.